# There is a way to export to STL without the visible files keeping the boolean modifiers

Tags: modifiers, export, stl

Im try to extrude with boolean modifiers. It looks like this with the hidden objects: [image]

I saw several tutorials where there is a button that says "apply" and they can delete the object, they seem to be older versions of blender. The main problem is that when extorting to stl, selecting the objects I want, the "boolean modifers" are not applied and they appear like this:[image]

Comment: They hid the apply button on you. Click on the downward pointing arrow next to the camera on the modifier panel. Apply them top to bottom.

Comment: You can also hover the mouse over the modifier to get the blue outline round it and then use CTRL-A to apply it..

Comment: Thankyou very much it wortks